# Normalized Database Diagram

Tags: mysql

So I am working on my DB design skills, and have tried to create a normalized MySQL database. Here is the diagram:

[image]

- The reason I added the Address table is to break the address fields into separate columns, making the geography more searchable (i.e. search for zipcode).
- Employer to Post will be a 1 (employer) to many (post(s))
- My idea for position, since there will be a set number of positions would be to seed a table (Position) and store the position id in the Post table
- Location works under the same premise of Address on the Employer table, however it may vary from the address on the employer table, earning it it's own table.
- Finally, Industry will be seeded just like the Position table.

I would appreciate constructive criticism, as I am still working on becoming better at my schema design.

Comment: When two tables have the some column structure (as Location and Address do here) That is almost always an indication that they should be the same table (conceptually and logically, even if separated physically for performance reasons).

Comment: So ask yourself, "What is the design assumption that leads me to think that Address and Location are separate entities rather than the same one?"

Comment: Well, the structure is the same, however Address would be the primary address, where location could be different depending on Post.. So I am not sure, to be honest.. Can I have a "primary" address in the Address table?

Comment: The relationship between Employer and Address is 1-N; but the relationship between Position and Location is 1-1. Therefore, each Address must have a FK to the Employer, and each Position must have a FK to the Address, with a transitive relationship to the Employer *via* the Address table.

Answer (score 1):

When two tables have the some column structure (as Location and Address do here) that is almost always an indication that they should be the same table (conceptually and logically, even if separated physically for performance reasons).

So ask yourself, "What is the design assumption that leads me to think that Address and Location are separate entities rather than the same one?"

Answer:
The relationship between Employer and Address is 1-N; but the relationship between Post and Location is 1-1. Therefore, each Address must have a FK to the Employer, and each Post must have a FK to the Address, with a transitive relationship to the Employer via the Address table.

Comment: Do you mean "Location" or "Position"?

Comment: @Chris" Post actually - corrected now

Comment: In other words, a Post is related to a particular Employer by virtue of being at an Address belonging to that Employer.

Comment: to ensure that I am fully understanding your explaination, I have revised my diagram: http://imgur.com/95nnz1r Now with the updated setup, the "primary" address would be the Address key on Employer and the "Location" address would be the key on Post?

Comment: @Chris: Two points: 1) The transitive closure relation between Post and Employer should go, as it is a denormalization. 2) You should put cardinality markers on your relationships, as they fundamentally affect the meaning of your diagram. Use whatever notation you are comfortable with, but do something.

Comment: unfortunately I haven't been able to find a definition regarding DB management for "transitive closure" I am assuming you mean the id_Post to Post's id column, however if I get rid of that connection, how will I maintain a relationship (1-N) between Employer and Post? As for cardinality, I will add to my diagram:  http://imgur.com/cQbxO71 . To summarize: One employer can have many posts. One Employer must have 1 "main" Address. One Post must have 1 Address. 1 Post must have 1 position. 1 Post must have 1 Industry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17858/discussion-between-chris-and-pieter-geerkens).